# How to display images edge to edge on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to display images edge to edge on mobile devices. The issue is that the container's max-width is set to 90%. So I've created the following class with custom CSS to use on images that I want displayed edge to edge of a mobile device screen:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.my-full-width-feature-image {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

My issue is that the above CSS code is also making the figcaption display edge to edge. Is there a way to only apply my class to the img element?

I've already tried ".my-full-width-feature-image img" but that doesn't seem to work either.

Below is how the HTML is arranged on my WordPress website.

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large my-full-width-feature-image">
<img width="780" height="520" src="https://nomadandinlove.com/wp-content/uploads/swapfiets_review.jpg" data-src="https://nomadandinlove.com/wp-content/uploads/swapfiets_review.jpg" alt="swapfiets bike sharing bicycle with blue tire in berlin with cherry blossoms in the background">
<figcaption>Cherry blossom hunting in Berlin with our monthly bike rental, Swapfiets</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, I discovered that I have a plugin that was placing all my img elements inside a div element.

So I just needed to change my custom code as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.my-full-width-feature-image div {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Now only the img element which is within the div is displaying edge to edge and the figcaption element is left unchanged.